# Need help using a PySimpleGUI TABLE with Sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, tkinter, pysimplegui

I'm trying to delete a row from my pysimplegui table that will also delete the same row data from my sqlite3 database. Using events, I've tried to use the index eg. -TABLE- {'-TABLE-': [1]} to index the row position using values['-TABLE-'] like so:

```
if event == 'Delete':
        row_index = 0
        for num in values['-TABLE-']:
            row_index = num + 1
        c.execute('DELETE FROM goals WHERE item_id = ?', (row_index,))
        conn.commit()
        window.Element('-TABLE-').Update(values=get_table_data())
```

I realized that this wouldn't work since I'm using a ROW_ID in my database that Auto-increments with every new row of data and stays fixed like so (this is just to show how my database is set up):

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('goals.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE goals (item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, goal_name text, goal_type text)''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Is there a way to use the index ( values['-TABLE-'] ) to find the data inside the selected row in pysimplegui and then using the selected row's data to find the row in my sqlite3 database to delete it, or is there any other way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

////////////////////////////////////////

FIX:
Upon more reading into the docs I discovered a .get() method. This method returns a nested list of all Table Rows, the method is callable on the element of '-TABLE-'. Using values['-TABLE-'] I can also find the row index and use the .get() method to index the specific list where the Data lays which I want to delete.
Here is the edited code that made it work for me:

```
    if event == 'Delete':
        row_index = 0
        for num in values['-TABLE-']:
            row_index = num 

        # Returns nested list of all Table rows
        all_table_vals = window.element('-TABLE-').get()

        # Index the selected row 
        object_name_deletion = all_table_vals[row_index]

        # [0] to Index the goal_name of my selected Row
        selected_goal_name = object_name_deletion[0]

        c.execute('DELETE FROM goals WHERE goal_name = ?', (selected_goal_name,))
        conn.commit()
        window.Element('-TABLE-').Update(values=get_table_data())
```

Comment: How do you get data from sqlite3 and insert them to pysimplegui table?

Comment: I use a pysimplegui window to get data into my sqlite3 database and to display the sqlite3 database data to the table, I created a function that selects the relevant fields from each row of my database and set it equal to the values of my table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example to delete a row from table

```py
import sqlite3

def deleteRecord():
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")

        # Deleting single record now
        sql_delete_query = """DELETE from SqliteDb_developers where id = 6"""
        cursor.execute(sql_delete_query)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Record deleted successfully ")
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to delete record from sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("the sqlite connection is closed")

deleteRecord()
```

In your case `id` will me the name of any column name which has  `unique` value for every row in the`table` of the `database`

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my problem is not about being able to Delete a row from a sqlite table itself, its more the problem of having PysimpleGui return row data to me from the pysimplegui table so that I can use that data to delete the row in sqlite3.